# Julia Vector: Excessive Memory Usage

Tags: arrays, memory, vector, julia

I want to brute force an 64-bit RSA encrypted text using a meet-in-the-middle attack (This is for university, nothing malicious).

To do this, I essentially created a Julia vector with 2^34 `BigInt` values and broadcasted the `powermod()` method on it to replace the values with the results.

```
v = powermod.(collect(1:2^34), e, n)
```

`n` in this case is 1024-bits long which should theoretically result in a vector of 2^34 * 1024 bits size plus overhead. However, if I try to create a smaller vector (E.g., 2^20) it will already allocate 4GB of memory.

```
const e = 65537
const n = 146524179203462820907751077702895222709717245613911342138636679265720963659264803540209990978140003809112749926543448691815554807130673470903067642157383639213843567573216381956709789503739105865173848988830139432801516289108538638198344024523424071181688467967187076534718264943427915623567859427045475866239

@time begin
    v = (powermod.(collect(1:2^24), e, n))
end
```

**Output of @time**:

```
125.598926 seconds (117.44 M allocations: 4.000 GiB, 5.35% gc time)
```

Not sure what and if I am doing something wrong here. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Why are you `collect`ing the range? Julia is perfectly capable iterating over the range object without allocating it into a vector.

Comment: Please provided a MWE including the `@time` line that prints the posted result, your code as is would not even run because `e` and `n` are not defined. It's not apparent where you made a `BigInt` array.

Comment: @NilsGudat Thank you for pointing that out. However, this will only reduce the allocated memory to `3.875 GiB`

Comment: @BatWannaBe I edited the post to provide a MWE. This will take a while to execute, but you can reduce the 24 to a smaller number for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, when you're using a `BigInt` you're using a different method of `powermod` which isn't allocation free:

```
julia> @btime powermod(1000, e, 100);
  370.048 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime powermod(1000, e, n);
  6.320 μs (9 allocations: 280 bytes)

julia> @which powermod(1000, e, 100)
powermod(x::Integer, p::Integer, m::T) where T<:Integer in Base at intfuncs.jl:358

julia> @which powermod(1000, e, n)
powermod(x::Integer, p::Integer, m::BigInt) in Base.GMP at gmp.jl:615
```

so you're not just allocating the result vector, but also during intermediate calculations. There's quite a few discussions on the Julia Discourse around the performance limitations of `BigInt`s, but I've never really worked with them so unfortunately don't have any advice on how to speed things up here!

Comment: I see.. Thanks a lot! I wonder why the memory is not just freed up after the result has been returned by the powermod-function.

Comment: The memory reported by @time is the total amount of memory ever allocated during execution, which includes freed memory. Check `Base.summarysize(v)` for the actual allocated memory you end up with.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that can be indexed and iterated like `v`, but it does the calculation upon indexing. Since it doesn't allocate an array of results, you cannot set an index like `v[i] = x`, which might be something you need.

```
struct Laz{F}
  f::F
  size::Int64
end

# v[i]
function Base.getindex(v::Laz, i)
  if i < 1 || i > v.size
    throw(BoundsError(v, i))
  else
    v.f(i)
  end
end

# for el in v
function Base.iterate(v::Laz, state=1)
  if state > v.size
    nothing
  else
    (v[state], state+1)
  end
end

# enables collect(v_lazy) to unlazy the array
Base.length(v::Laz) = v.size

v_lazy = Laz( (x) -> powermod(x, e, n) , 2^24)
```

`v_lazy` gets to go on the stack and `Base.summarysize(v_lazy)` reports 8 bytes, so this is as memory-efficient as you can get. Each time you index and compute `BigInt`s, you do allocate, though. If you iterate `v_lazy` you end up allocating a proportionate amount of memory to `v`, just allocated and freed incrementally instead of all at once in a massive array.